# Calendar heatmap with Years as legend/visual map using Apache ECharts

Tags: apache, calendar, heatmap, echarts

I am trying to use Apache Echarts in my application and stumbled upon how to display multi-year heat map using calendar co-ordinate system in ECharts.  Please find the concept image below.  Any help is deeply appreciated.

[Multi Year Calendar Heatmap with ECharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFjmj.jpg)

Thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Echarts component legend may contain [`multiple legend`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend). Just make second at bottom, then capture [`click event`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.legendselectchanged) on legend and change chart data by [`setOption`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption).

Comment: Hi Sergey,  thank you for the tip.  This worked for me.